# RstDocument in kivy

Tags: kivy, restructuredtext

I noticed that math is not supported in RstDocument class.

Is this a bug or not implemented yet?

I tried The area of a circle is :math:`A_\text{c} = (\pi/4) d^2`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's implemented.